# Время жизни переменных в лямбде функции?

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, c++14, лямбда-выражение

Время жизни переменных, которые передают в область захвата(в квадратные скобки) лямбды-функции по значению.

Не смог придумать нормальный пример. Вымышленный код:

```
QVector<SomeClass*> objs = initObjs();
for (int i = 0; i < objs.size(); ++i) {
    // SomeClass::signal(QString)
    connect(objs[i], &SomeClass::signal, this, [this, i] (QString msg) { qDebug() << i << msg; });
}
```

В этом участке кода я хочу от массива объектов выводить сообщения, с индексом объекта. Это должно работать? Пример вывода, который я ожидал бы увидеть:

> 0 i'm obj with index 0
>
> 6 signal from obj[6]
>
> 2 some msg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Объекты, переданные по значению в список захвата лямбда-выражения, копируются в результирующий объект-замыкание, и их время жизни совпадает с временем жизни объекта-замыкания.